# using printf on array of Strings to format output

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, printf

For one of my assignments, I have to calculate the heat index and use printf to format the output to display neatly, like this:

```
                   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov Dec
________________________________________________________________________________________
Temperature (F):   1.1   2.2   3.3   4.4   5.5   6.6   7.7   8.8   9.9   10   11   12
Humidity (%):      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10.3 11.2 12.1
HI (F):            1.1   2.2   3.3   4.4   5     7     6     8     9     10   11   12
```

The problem is, I don't know how to format an array of Strings because the array of Strings contains numbers. In my program, do I have to convert my array that I declared as a String to like a double or a float and then format it with printf? Also, I don't know how I can use an array for a calculation. In my assignment, I have to use two arrays to calculate the heat index. Trying to solve this problem, I tried performing the calculations individually by indexes. The problem is, the program will just show the whole entire array. The program is reading two files and storing the text in an array, one array for each file. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The first file contains this:

70.3   70.8   73.8   77.0   80.7   83.4   84.5   84.4   83.4   80.2   76.3   72.0

and the second contains this:

69 67 66 64 66 69 67 67 70 69 69 70

and my code is this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author timothylee
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class HeatIndex {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here

    // create months
    System.out.println("Jan" +  "    Feb" + "    Mar" + "    April" + "  May" + "    June" + 
            "   July" + "   Aug" + "    Sep" + "    Oct" + "    Nov" + "    Dec");

    // create line
    System.out.println("_________________________________________________"
            + "__________________________________");

    // // read KeyWestTemp.txt

    // create token1
    String token1 = "";

    // create Scanner inFile1
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File
    ("/Users/timothylee/KeyWestTemp.txt")).
            useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    // create temps1
    List<String> temps1 = new LinkedList<String>();

    // while loop
    while(inFile1.hasNext()){

        // find next
        token1 = inFile1.next();

        // initialize temps1
        temps1.add(token1);
    }

    // close inFile1
    inFile1.close();

    // create array
    String[] tempsArray1 = temps1.toArray(new String[0]);

    // for-each loop
    for(String s : tempsArray1){

        // display Temp (F)
        System.out.print("Temp (F) ");

        // display s
        System.out.printf(tempsArray1[0]);

        // create new line
        System.out.println();
    }

    // create token2
    String token2 = "";

    // create Scanner inFile2
    Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File
    ("/Users/timothylee/KeyWestHumid.txt")).
            useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    // create temps2
    List<String> temps2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    // while loop
    while(inFile2.hasNext()){

        // find next
        token2 = inFile2.next();

        // initialize temps2
        temps2.add(token2);
    }

    // close inFile2
    inFile2.close();

    // create array
    String[] tempsArray2 = temps2.toArray(new String[0]);

    // for-each loop
    for(String ss : tempsArray2){

        // create Humidity (%)
        System.out.print("Humidity (%) ");

        // display ss
        System.out.printf(tempsArray2[0]);
    }

    // calculate heat index


}

}
```

and my output is this:

```
run:
Jan    Feb    Mar    April  May    June   July   Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
___________________________________________________________________________________
Temp (F) 70.3   70.8   73.8   77.0   80.7   83.4   84.5   84.4   83.4   80.2   76.3   72.0   
Humidity (%) 69 67 66 64 66 69 67 67 70 69 69 70BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html). You need to use the `format()` method, for example something like this would give you the spacing you need in your first line.

```
formatter.format("%15s%5s%5s%5s",months[0],months[1],months[2],months[3]); //and so on for all twelve months
```

As for numbers you need to use

```
formatter.format("%5.1f",myFloat);
```

The first digit denotes how many characters you use for your natural part and the second digit how many characters for your decimal part. Seeing that all your numbers have only 1 decimal digit and you need spacing between numbers, use the `%5.1f` format.

Comment: In the first code sample, the format method expects four strings.

Comment: Yeah I'm assuming he's using an array of strings containing the abbreviated 12 months.

Comment: Ok. I hadn't contemplated that. If you edit the answer I can remove the downvote.